# Prevent shifting of rows in auto-updating sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-forms, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am struggling with an automatically updating spreadsheet that is connected to a Google Form.

Whenever there is a new accomplished answer in the Form it is adding a row in the spreadsheet, resulting in a shifting of my whole spreadsheet.

Take a look at the picture to understand the problem:

[image: Before answer]

[image: After answer]

As you can see, the row is created and shifts everything apart.
Is there a way, to prevent that, like protecting the area from K-P ("Preis pp." the gray-colored one until the end)?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @user0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_krroK2SS_xo2hoCg36r_icBf3FNrchHjvaksFLCSmI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to crate Sheet2 and move columns **M:Q** there and then call it back from Sheet2 with **`ARRAYFORMULA`**.

Delete everything in column **K** and paste this in **K1** cell:

```
={"Preis pp.";
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF($E2:E = "Ja"; $Q$3; )+
              IF($G2:G = "Ja"; $Q$6; )+
              IF($I2:I = "Ja"; $Q$9; ))}
```

Delete everything in columns **M**, **N**, **O**, **Q** and paste this in **M1** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Tabellenblatt2!B1:F)
```

[image: 0]

---

### **[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vji7Ehr0EMENBn07k2Yb3TI6pl0LmVm_C27AmiGPTzQ/edit#gid=1006379896)**

**side note:** also you will need to color your cells with Conditional formatting instead of doing it manually

Comment: Wow thank you so much, I will try it out in a few hours

Answer (score 0):

If you really really want to do it without Sheet2 you can do so too. Delete columns **M:O** and paste in cell **M1**:

```
={""\""\""; "Zusammenfassung"\"Zusammenfassung"\"Zusammenfassung"; "Männlich:"\
"Webilich:"\"Sonstige:";COUNTIF(D:D;"männlich")\COUNTIF(D:D;"weiblich")\COUNTIFS(D$2:D; 
"<>männlich";D$2:D;"<>weiblich";D$2:D;"<>");""\""\"";"Pulli:"\"Pulli:"\"Pulli:";
COUNTIFS(D:D;"männlich";E:E;"Ja")\COUNTIFS(D:D;"weiblich";E:E;"Ja")\COUNTIFS(D$2:D; 
"<>männlich";D$2:D;"<>weiblich";D$2:D;"<>";E$2:E;"Ja");"T-Shirt:"\"T-Shirt:"\"T-Shirt:";
COUNTIFS(D:D;"männlich";G:G;"Ja")\COUNTIFS(D:D;"weiblich";G:G;"Ja")\COUNTIFS(D$2:D; 
"<>männlich";D$2:D;"<>weiblich";D$2:D;"<>";G$2:G;"Ja");"Beutel:"\"Beutel:"\"Beutel:";
COUNTIFS(D:D;"männlich";I:I;"Ja")\COUNTIFS(D:D;"weiblich";I:I;"Ja")\COUNTIFS(D$2:D; 
"<>männlich";D$2:D;"<>weiblich";D$2:D;"<>";I$2:I;"Ja");""\""\"";"Summe insgesamt"\""\"";
"Pulli"\COUNTIF(E:E;"Ja")\"";"T-Shirt"\COUNTIF(G:G;"Ja")\"";"Beutel"\COUNTIF(I:I;"Ja")\
"";""\""\"";"Größen Pulli:"\""\"";"XS"\COUNTIF(F:F;"XS")\"";"S"\COUNTIF(F:F;"S")\"";"M"\
COUNTIF(F:F;"M")\"";"L"\COUNTIF(F:F;"L")\"";"XL"\COUNTIF(F:F;"XL")\"";"XXL"\COUNTIF(F:F;
"XXL")\"";""\""\"";"Größen T-Shirt:"\""\"";"XS"\COUNTIF(H:H;"XS")\"";"S"\COUNTIF(H:H;
"S")\"";"M"\COUNTIF(H:H;"M")\"";"L"\COUNTIF(H:H;"L")\"";"XL"\COUNTIF(H:H;"XL")\"";"XXL"\
COUNTIF(H:H;"XXL")\""}
```

[image: 0]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tPYWLC-RG3QXfmbCDF-T8ITFeq1X7tmimetk3MO3Hn4/edit#gid=1006379896)